# How to open file that saved in a folder under wwwroot in the browser?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, file, href

I have this line of code in my view.

```
<a href="~abcdefg" target="_blank">Preview file</a>
```

What must I put in the href in-order to open the file from a folder under wwwroot in the Visual Studio?

Thanks!

I mean a word document, not images.

Comment: You need to provide controller and action name which open the file for view/download, usually in format `@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done as follows. This open the file in a new tab.

```
<a href="images/Bangladesh.jpg" target="_blank">Preview</a>

 //or

<a href="@Url.Content("images/Bangladesh.jpg")" target="_blank">Preview2</a>
```

Note: `Bangladesh.jpg` file is in the `images` folder under `wwwroot`

Comment: I mean word document.

Comment: Why you didn't mention this in the question please? Please always ask clearly what do you want.

Comment: Ok I will RT TanviraArjel